# Complete residue system for all $p$ implies infinite prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let be $\mathcal{P} \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ with the following property:

*For all $p \ge 2$, $p$ prime number, $ \exists \ \{a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_p \} \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ which is a complete residue system modulo $p.$*

Does this implies that $\mathcal{P}$ has infinite prime numbers?

Comment: Can I just take $\mathcal{P} = \{ n\in \mathbb{N} \,|\, n \text{ is not prime}\}$?

Comment: No. You may take $\mathcal{P}$ as the set of the non-prime sums of two squares, for instance. This particular $\mathcal{P}$ has density zero and does not contain any prime.

Comment: Or you may take $\mathcal{P}$ as the set of "prime numbers plus seven or thirteen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.
$$
\mathcal{P} = \{ n\in \mathbb{N} \,|\, n \text{ is not prime}\}
$$
contains no primes and contains a complete residue system mod $p$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good counterexample.